# Jquery Autocomplete and ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, autocomplete

**Before the purists attack me, I know combining jquery and angular the way I am is not "correct"**

Ok on with the show.

I have a text box with jQueryUI autocomplete attached to it. This works great! I also have a button with an ng-show attribute that evaluates the validity of the entry in the textbox. This also works correctly if I type the name out manually. However. If I start typing and then click on the autocomplete entry - the ng-show function does not evaluate. I have to then manually add a space or something to the end of the text box to force it to run.

Any ideas on how to get ng-show to work with jQueryUI autocomplete?

```
<p><input id="txtUniqueUser" ng-model="selectedUserName" name="UniqueUser" type="text" placeholder="Search For User" class="input-xlarge" style="width:80%"></p>
<p ng-show="isValidName()"><button type="button" ng-model="selectedUserName" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Begin!</button></p>

$scope.isValidName = function(){
        if($scope.uniqueDisplaynames.indexOf($scope.selectedUserName) != -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };
```

**I added this to make it work:**

```
$('#txtUniqueUser').on("autocompletechange",function(event,ui)
            {
                $scope.selectedUserName = $('#txtUniqueUser')[0].value;
                $scope.$apply();
                $scope.isValidName();
            });


ARApp.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                    // elem is a jquery lite object if jquery is not present,
                    // but with jquery and jquery ui, it will be a full jquery object.
            elem.autocomplete({
                source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), //from your service
                minLength: 2
            });
        }
    };
});

ARApp.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function($scope) {
    return {
        getSource: function($scope) {

            return [$scope.uniqueDisplaynames];
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because since the value of the input is modified by jQuery, angularjs is unaware about the changes.

Disclaimer: Not tested

AngularJS reacts to the changes made to the scope variables using the [$digest](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24digest) cycle, so when autocomplete changes the value of the input element those are not getting copied to the model object associated with it.

An easy workaround should be to fire the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on the [autocomplete change event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change) of the element